# Is size of char_traits<char16_t>::int_type not large enough?

Tags: c++

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int, char **) {
  std::basic_stringstream<char16_t> stream;

  stream.put(u'\u0100');
  std::cout << " Bad: " << stream.bad() << std::endl;

  stream.put(u'\uFFFE');
  std::cout << " Bad: " << stream.bad() << std::endl;

  stream.put(u'\uFFFF');
  std::cout << " Bad: " << stream.bad() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
 Bad: 0                                                                                                                                                                                
 Bad: 0                                                                                                                                                                                
 Bad: 1
```

It seems the reason the badbit gets set is because 'put' sets the badbit if the character equals std::char_traits::eof(). I can now no longer put to the stream.

At http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits it states:

> int_type: an integer type that can hold all values of char_type plus
>   EOF

But if char_type is the same as int_type (uint_least16_t) then how can this be true?

Comment: I think 0xFFFF and 0xFFFE are not unicode codepoints, right?

Comment: They are, although we're getting a bit deep: http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum9.html

Comment: I just tried streaming and it does not set the badbit: stream << u'\uFFFF';

Comment: This also works: `char16_t c = u'\uFFFF'; stream.write( &c, 1 );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard is quite explicit, `std::char_traits<char16_t>::int_type` is a typedef for `std::uint_least16_t`, see  [char.traits.specializations.char16_t], which also says:

> The member `eof()` shall return an implementation-defined constant that cannot appear as a valid UTF-16 code unit.

I'm not sure precisely how that interacts with http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum9.html but existing practice in the major C++ implementations is to use the all-ones bit pattern for `char_traits<char16_t>::eof()`, even when `uint_least16_t` has exactly 16 bits.

After a bit more thought, I think it's possible for implementations to meet the Character traits requirements by making `std::char_traits<char16_t>::to_int_type(char_type)` return U+FFFD when given U+FFFF. This satisfies the requirement for `eof()` to return:

> a value `e` such that `X::eq_int_type(e,X::to_int_type(c))` is `false` for all values `c`.

This would also ensure that it's possible to distinguish success and failure when checking the result of `basic_streambuf<char16_t>::sputc(u'\uFFFF')`, so that it only returns `eof()` on failure, and returns `u'\ufffd'` otherwise.

I'll try that. I've created https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80624 to track this in GCC.

I've also reported an [issue](http://wg21.link/lwg2959) against the standard, so we can fix the "cannot appear as a valid UTF-16 code unit" wording, and maybe fix it some other way too.

Comment: It sounds like in  "cannot appear as a *valid UTF-16 code unit*" it considers Unicode noncharachter as non valid UTF-16 code unit, so that \uFFFF can represent eof. Besides in the page you linked "Noncharacters in the Unicode Standard are intended for *internal use* and have no standard interpretation when exchanged outside the context of internal use. However, they are not illegal in interchange nor do they cause ill-formed Unicode text." The internal use could be to represent eof without the need of an extra bit.

Comment: The wording in the C++ standard was written when the Unicode spec said "and that should never be interchanged" so it seemed clear that noncharacters were reserved and could be used for eof. After the 2013 corrigendum that's not so clear. They might have broken the C++ standard.

Comment: I found this: http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#nonchar8, so noncharacters seem to be valid.

Comment: Section 21.2.1 of the standard(N3797) has a table that says for eof(): "yields: a value e such that
X::eq_int_type(e,X::to_-
int_type(c)) is false for all
values c." and a footnote: "233) If eof() can be held in char_type then some iostreams operations may give surprising results". So I think the standard itself it is correct, and its cppreference and the implementations of char_traits<char16_t> which are incorrect.

Comment: Correction to my above comment: You correctly point out the typedef of int_type to std::uint_least16_t, which should be something else (a type of greater size than char_type, however that should be worded). That could be a bug in the standard, but not for me to say!

Comment: @lrm29 thanks for the link to the FAQ, it looks like http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#nonchar10 has the answer and C++ implementations could replace occurrences of the character they use for eof, transforming it into another noncharacter. So I might need to change libstdc++ to transform U+FFFF to U+FFFD.

Comment: The section on sentinels is particularly interesting as it gives a bit of the history behind noncharacters. Really though, it's all a bit of a mess isn't it...

Comment: cppreference now mentions what eof()s are in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits

Comment: Thanks @Cubbi. The problem is the way that this is specified, it's not possible for EOF to be an invalid UTF-16 code unit! It turns out this has already been brought up but is marked as not a defect: [LWG issue 1200](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#1200). I'm awaiting a response from a post in [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/embed/?place=forum%2Fstd-discussion&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fisocpp.org%2Fforums%2Fiso-c-standard-discussion#!topic/std-discussion/1zfn6WgHz8k)

Comment: I've asked for a new defect report to be opened. 1200 doesn't actually describe the core of the problem, and the suggested fixes don't solve anything. It's a shame the `int_type` typedef wasn't changed to a bigger size back in 2009 though, before it was too late to change :-(

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is interesting, that:

```
stream.put(u'\uFFFF');
```

sets the `badbit`, while:

```
stream << u'\uFFFF';
char16_t c = u'\uFFFF'; stream.write( &c, 1 );
```

does not set `badbit`.

This answer only focus on the differences.

So let's check gcc's source code in [bits/ostream.tcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc;h=e96bad8121000470fd6dcfc77c946d1d1ec08bd5;hb=HEAD#l149), line 164~165, we can see that `put()` checks if the value equals to `eof()`, and set the `badbit`.

```
if (traits_type::eq_int_type(__put, traits_type::eof()))  // <== It checks the value!
    __err |= ios_base::badbit;
```

From line 196, we can see `write()` does not have this logic, it only checks if all the chars are written to the buffer.

This explains the behavior.

From `std::basic_ostream::put`'s [description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/put/):

> Internally, the function accesses the output sequence by first
>   constructing a sentry object. Then (if good), it inserts c into its
>   associated stream buffer object as if calling its member function
>   sputc, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.

It does not tell anything about the check of `eof()`.

So I would think this is either a bug in document or a bug in implementation.

Comment: Please don't past copyrighted code to StackOverflow if you are not the copyright holder. StackOverflow's terms don't allow that. I suggest you link to a copy of the code in the source repo instead.

Comment: Thanks for the note, updated the answer to add link of the code.

Comment: That doxygen copy of the source is from 2004, how about https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc;h=e96bad8121000470fd6dcfc77c946d1d1ec08bd5;hb=HEAD instead

Comment: _"It does not tell anything about the check of eof()."_ It has to do that, to tell if the call to `basic_streambuf::sputc(c)` succeeded, because it returns `eof` on failure, and `to_int_type(c)` otherwise.

Comment: Right, I just noticed this. But this is the problem though.

Comment: Not if `to_int_type(u'\uFFFF')` returns something that is not equal to `eof()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what you mean by "large enough". `char16_t` is not "a type large enough to hold any Unicode character including those which I'm not allowed to use". *You* chose to try to cram [`\uFFFF`, which is "reserved for internal use"](http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum9.html), into a `char16_t`, and thus you are the one at fault. The program is simply doing as you instructed.

Comment: I stated in the question what I mean by large enough. An integer type that can hold all values of char_type plus EOF. If char_type and int_type are the same type (uint_least16_t), then how can that statement be satisfied?

Comment: `uint_least16_t` is **at least** 16 bits but **can** be more. `char_type` only needs to be 16 bits, no more. To satisfy the requirement, `int_type` would have to be at least 17 bits, but since there is no 17-bit integer type, the next highest size is usually 32 bits. So despite what `cppreference.com` says, `int_type` might not be `uint_least16_t`, it might be something larger.

Comment: Also, I should be able to put the noncharacters into a char16_t: "type for UTF-16 character representation, required to be large enough to represent any UTF-16 code unit (16 bits)"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's a problem though, because to be able to store EOF as well, it needs to be more than 16 bits, not at least 16 bits.

Comment: @lrm29: _"I stated in the question what I mean by large enough. An integer type that can hold all values of char_type plus EOF"_ Well I have no idea how you arrived at that expectation, given that `EOF` is one of those values. It's like saying you want a box big enough to hold everything that can fit in the box, plus something extra.

Comment: @lrm29: that is exactly what I said: "*To satisfy the requirement, `int_type` would have to be **at least 17 bits***", so `int_type` should not be `uint_least16_t`, unless `uint_least16_t` is larger than 16 bits (which it can be, by definition).

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: "*Well I have no idea how you arrived at that expectation, given that EOF is one of those values*" - it is not an expectation, it is a documented requirement. UTF-16 uses all 16 bits, and EOF must be handled **in addition to** those 16 bits, so its value cannot be one that UTF-16 uses. And your box metaphor is misleading. Of course you can have a box that is larger than what is actually stored in it with room to spare. There is a limit to how much is stored.  Same with UTF-16.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how do you square _"`int_type` should not be `uint_least16_t`, unless `uint_least16_t` is larger than 16 bits"_ with the fact that the standard says `char_traits<char16_t>::int_type` must be `uint_least16_t`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: then the standard is not following its own requirements: "*For a certain character container type `char_type`, a related container type `INT_T` shall be a type or class which can represent all of the valid characters converted from the corresponding `char_type` values, as well as an end-of-file value, `eof()`*" (section 21.2.2), and "*The member `eof()` shall return an implementation-defined constant that cannot appear as a valid UTF-16
code unit.*" (section 21.2.3.2).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Which means the value of `eof()` must be outside of the 16 bits used by UTF-16 code units, and UTF-16 uses all 16 bits, so `int_type` cannot be `uint_least16_t` unless it is implemented as more than 16 bits.  So I think the standard is wrong in defining `int_type` as `uint_least16_t` for `char16_t`, it should be `int` or `int32_t` or `int_least32_t` or something more like that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no it doesn't have to mean that. The OP provided a link to the FAQ, which suggests another solution that doesn't require extra bits: http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#nonchar10